# How do i import an ejs file into haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ejs

I have a Rails application, and would like to import an ejs file into my existing haml file

index.haml:

```
- str = controller.render_to_string file: "random.ejs", layout: false
= str.html_safe
```

ranodm.ejs (works):

```
<div>Random</div>
```

**ranodm.ejs (DOES NOT WORK):**

```
<img src="<% if (sc_image) { %><%= sc_image %><% } else { %>/assets/arrow-head-260x260.png<% } %>">
```

I get the following error:

```
Syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...('<img src="'); if (sc_image) { ;@output_buffer.append= ( sc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like rails is interpreting the `ejs` file as ruby and chokes when it hits the javascript syntax. Here's 2 suggestions:

1. Use the [ruby-ejs](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-ejs/) gem to render the partial to a text string using javsccript.

   `EJS.evaluate("Hello <%= name %>", :name => "world")`

   `# => "Hello world"`

   You would just need to load the file in to pass its contents to `evaluate` without trying to parse  it first. `File.open("app/views/controller_name/_my_awesome_template.html.ejs").read`
2. You could rewrite the `ejs` partial in ruby unless you're using it elsewhere in a javascript context.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the conditional to avoid using brackets like this:

```
<img src="<% sc_image ? sc_image : "/assets/arrow-head-260x260.png"%>"
```